# Anyone know how to calculate the DOCUMENT dimensions, NOT the VIEWPORT in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, cross-browser

Just to make sure everyone understands what I am asking for, I will run through what I believe are the basic distinctions between document, window, and viewport....

WINDOW is the entire browser window, including all nav bars, etc....

VIEWPORT is the portion of the window used to view the current XHTML/HTML/Flash document...

DOCUMENT is the actual content area, akin to the body but includes ALL of the page's content. Only a portion of it is visible at any one time in the VIEWPORT (unless the page is the same size or smaller than the viewport).

Now, there are many great answers for how to get the VIEWPORT dimensions. I am already well versed in that... cross-browser and all.

What I really need to know is a simple, cross-browser solution that will give me the dimensions of the actual DOCUMENT in all browsers (no versions older than 3 years).

I thought I found a great solution here once... long ago... but now I cannot find it.

Anyone? Thanks for the read and hopefully someone can help.

P.S. Did I mention I DO NOT want solutions for calculating the VIEWPORT? OR THE WINDOW?

UPDATE: this solution MUST work in Opera 10.x, FireFox 3.6.x, IE 7/8/x, Flock 2.x, Safari 4.x... None of the answers below work in all browsers....

So, if you have not tested it in all, please do not respond to the question.

Comment: So you want the viewport dimensions, right? :)

Comment: Thanks for having a sense of humor about it... you would be amazed at the people who post answers to questions without fully understanding what the issue even is... :-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but none of these answers were what I was looking for. In the end, I decided to just stick with document.body.getWidth() and document.body.getHeight() in Prototype.

Answer (score 3):

document.body.scrollHeight and document.body.scrollWidth.

Should give it to you.

Answer (score 3):

I stole this from jQuery's source and made a wrapper around it:

EDIT: Refactored the function so it returns both width and height in an array.

```
function getDocumentDimensions() {
    var d = document;
    return [
        Math.max(
            d.documentElement['clientHeight'],
            d.body['scrollHeight'],
            d.body['offsetHeight']
        ),
        Math.max(
            d.documentElement['clientWidth'],
            d.body['scrollWidth'],
            d.body['offsetWidth']
        )
     ]
};

getDocumentDimensions() // [1284, 1265]
```

the jQuery for this would be `$(document).height()` and width.

Comment: I am not understanding the point of the function? Does document.body.scrollheight/scrollwidth not always return the greatest value? I felt these two values would suffice on their own or am I missing something?

Comment: I like where this is headed... but unless I didi something wrong, I could not get it to work properly in Firefox 3.6.x or Opera 10.x. It worked great in Safari. Of course, not that I am too worried about Opera, I was just hoping for the Holy Grail of a single function for all browser engines.... thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you wrap your entire contents into a DIV element with zero borders, padding and margins, then when the browser is finished rendering you can use [jQuery's  .height() method](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to interrogate the wrapping DIV for its actual height.

I have done this before, and I found I had specific problems with various browsers.  You may not run into those problems that I had, but I ended up settling on this solution.

Comment: use .outerHeight(true) if you'd like to measure the height including paddings and margins. (http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Comment: The OP didn't specify `jquery` **at all**. How is this getting an upvote?

Comment: @meder sorry, I'm just suggesting it, as OP may not have considered jQuery.  Besides, isn't jQuery still JavaScript?  Its only a framework/helper library not another language after all?

Comment: http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png In addition, I don't see why he has to wrap an entire div around everything. You can simply query the document object's properties for this..

Comment: @meder that is a bit overboard.  

I didn't suggest using jQuery to add two numbers together.  
I suggested it because OP is interacting with the DOM and because it is good leveling the playing field of doing common DOM things in different browsers that handle things slightly differently.

Comment: @meder I think youre taking this way too seriously, I wrapped it in a DIV because in my case using the document didn't work accurately in every browser version (I can't remember which, it was a while ago) If using the document works good for you then use that. This was just my answer, if you don't like it you don't have to vote me up.

Comment: @Roberto: I wouldn't be surprised about getting inaccurate or inconsistent (cross-browser) results using `document`, but how about getting the body element rather than adding a DIV wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar need and use this code.  It's not tested in opera/flock, but we cover all the other browsers.  Note that it's not always quite perfect, but does the job in 99%+ of the cases.

```
function getContentWidthHeight() {
    var pageWidth = 0; 
    var pageHeight = 0;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {
        pageWidth = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
        pageHeight = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    } 
    if (document.body.scrollHeight) {
        pageWidth = Math.max(pageWidth, document.body.scrollWidth);
        pageHeight = Math.max(pageHeight, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    if (document.body.offsetHeight) {
        pageWidth = Math.max(pageWidth, document.body.offsetWidth);
        pageHeight = Math.max(pageHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
    }
    if (document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
        pageWidth = Math.max(pageWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth);
        pageHeight = Math.max(pageHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
    }
    if (document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {
        pageWidth = Math.max(pageWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth);
        pageHeight = Math.max(pageHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);
    }
    return [ pageWidth, pageHeight ];
};
```